# Why does Hyper-V require hardware virtualization?

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

I know Hyper-V is type 1 or native hypervisor, meaning it sits on top of hardware and doesn't require an operating system, i.e. talks to the hardware through the ISA interface).

But I don't understand why does it require hardware assisted virtualization? Does it mean Hyper-V is not full native hypervisor because it requires another part (put in hardware)? Does every native hypervisor require hardware virtualization?

Answer (score 2):

Because without hardware virtualization it would have to run an emulation which comes with a BRUTAL performance implication. There is no way to do proper virtualiaztion without either interpreting a significant number of machine code, or have hardware support for this. EVERY native hypervisor requires hardware virtualization - which is, btw., nothing new... it was in the firstp rocessors mit 60s, iirc (196x). Yes, this is that old. VMS - the Mainframe operating system - is acutally short for... "Virtual Machine System". The processors back then had hardware virtualization.